# Select Tag Change Event Call on Selected Index Change

Tags: javascript

I have a select tag that has an eventListener on `change`.

Now I also have two different buttons that change it, that uses:

```
      (selectTag).selectedIndex++;
```

The above does what I want to achieve, but it does not call my function callback on `change`.

How would I go about doing that? Other Approaches welcomed.

I would prefer pure-JS solutions, (noJquery please).

Comment: Why not just call the function after incrementing selectedIndex?

Comment: @HattanShobokshi It's a lambda function...

Comment: possible duplicate of [onchange wont fire after programmatically changing html select dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958863/onchange-wont-fire-after-programmatically-changing-html-select-dropdown)

Comment: So give it a name, then you can call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [trigger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) *change* event when calling *click* handler on buttons:

```
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var button = document.querySelector("button")

select.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  alert(e.target.value)
});

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var event;

  try {
    event = new Event("change")
  } catch (e) {
    event =  document.createEvent("Event");
    event.initEvent("change", true, false);
  }

  select.selectedIndex++;
  select.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/IrikoBI/3/edit)

**Update:** I've changed it work in IE 10 and probably some others.

Comment: Great solution, but it does not seem to work in IE. Any fix you can think of?

Comment: I've updated the answer to work with IE 10 (and probably other versions). Still, it would be easier to use library like jQuery or Zepro.js to leverage browsers difference, that's what they are for after all.

Comment: Awesome Thanks! I would normally use Jquery, but I'm developing a HTML5 Windows8 App, so IE would be my only target in this case. Thanks again!

Comment: You can use jQuery in a Windows 8 HTML5 app.